# How to access local variables of a method while writing unit tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, reflection, scope

Given the code below:

```
public class Employee
{
    public void CalculateEmpSal(int empId,int salary)
    {      
        // local varibles
        int Basic; 
        int HRA;       

        // Calculate employee salary
        Basic = salry * (0.40);
        HRA = Basic * (0.50);
    }
}
```

Is it possible to write a unit test for the `CalculateEmpSal` method that can access the `Basic` and `HRA` local variables?  I couldn't access these variables using reflection. Is there another way to access them from my unit tests?

Comment: Reflection over here would not work as the scope of local variables are withing the curly braces only. Do try some other tricks :)

Comment: Unless the method returns something or has an external effect, then there  is nothing to test. In this specific example, there is literally nothing to test. Test the results of methods, not the internal implementation details.

Answer (score 7):

You can't... and you shouldn't want to.

You should be testing the side effects / state changes caused by your methods, not the low level implementation details.  As it stands, your method has no side effects, so there's nothing to test.

If you change it to return something useful (possibly `HRA`), then you'd have something to test outside the method.

```
public int CalculateEmpSal(int empId,int salary)
{      
    // local varibles
    int Basic; 
    int HRA;       

    // Calculate employee salary
    Basic = salry * (0.40);
    HRA = Basic * (0.50);
    return HRA;
}
```

If you're just trying to inspect the values, then you should step through the code with your debugger..

As an aside, you're using floating point numbers, with integers... are you *sure* you want to do that?

Comment: The above mentioned code block is a sample code . My requirement is to  check the HRA local varible value from my Unit Test code .. And the method should returns void only.

Comment: @rajasairam That doesn't change the fact that you can't.  When you're outside of the method, the variables simply don't exist.  The only way to inspect them is through the debugging API as the method is running and not even Typemock lets you do that, because it's a bad idea.  If you're calculating something then for it to be meaningful you *must* be doing something with it.  Passing it to another method, storing it in a class member etc.  These actions are testable.

Answer (score 1):

Your code requires a little refactoring in order to be properly testable and clean. There are several things that come to my mind here...

The `CalculateEmpSal(..)` receives a `int empId`. Why? Wouldn't this be a member of the `Employee` class?:

```
public class Employee
{
    private readonly int id;

    public Employee(int id)
    {
         this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Next thing is you cannot access local method variables through reflection, neither for testing, nor in any other situation. Reflection is not needed here. Your have two possibilities.

The best option would be to change the method to return an `int` with the value that you actually need. I'm not sure what `HRA` is, but this might be the value you actually need.

```
public int CalculateEmpSal(int salary)
{      
    var basic = salary * (0.40);
    return basic * (0.50); // this was HRA once..
}
```

If you need to access both of those values (`basic` and `HRA`) somewhere in your production code, you could either make them members of your `Employee` class:

```
public class Employee
{
    // ...

    public int basicSalary {get; private set;};
    public int hraSalary {get; private set;};

    public void CalculateSalary(int salary)
    {      
        this.basicSalary = salary * (0.40);
        this.hraSalary = this.basicSalary * (0.50); 
    }

    // ...
}
```

But this would lead to them being `0` if the `CalculateEmpSal` method was never called on the instance of `Employee`.

So I guess it would be better to source them out in a little wrapper-class or something else that suits your design. For Example:

```
public class SalaryInfo
{
    public int Salary {get; set;}
    public int Hra {get; set;}
}

public class Employee
{
    // ...

    public SalaryInfo CalculateSalary(int salary)
    {
        var retval = new SalaryInfo()
        {
            Salary = salary * (0.40),
            Hra = salary * (0.40) * (0.50) // *0.2 ...
        };

        return retval;
    }

    // ...
}
```

This way, you have public properties you can easily access in your unit tests.

Answer (score 1):

In your class you are setting the values of the variables which are then disposed of without being used. Given this fact what difference does it make if the values are wrong? You are not using them for anything anyway. Given the example you have I can replace it with this and the result is exactly the same:

```
public class Employee
{
    public void CalculateEmpSal(int empId,int salary)
    {                  
    }
}
```

Tests are about testing side effects and/or interactions. your method has no side effects or interactions and so is effectively an inefficient noop method and cannot be tested.

You must be doing something other than what you have shown in the example for you to know what the salary you have calculated is. That result is what you should be testing.